# Не работает стиль кнопки во фрагменте

Tags: android

Установил стиль для всех кнопок в приложении

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/button_style</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="button_style" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/white_blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Вот так выглядит кнопка в `XML`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_splash_screen_start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/start"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appCompatTextView"/>
```

Теперь фокус, если эта кнопка в `XML` от активити, то все работает. Если эта кнопка в `XML` от фрагмента то кнопка не реагирует на установленный стиль

Что делаю не так?

Не знаю важно или нет, но фрагмент использую вот этот

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

и активити вот такое

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

**EDIT**

Если устанавливаю стиль напрямую, то все работает

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_splash_screen_start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/start"
    style="@style/button_style"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appCompatTextView"/>
```

Comment: а если попробовать подключить напрямую стиль к кнопке?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko да, но тогда мне нужно будет этот стиль подключать к каждой кнопке отдельно

Comment: но вообще так работает?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko да, добавил в вопрос правку

Comment: а что если попробовать фрагмент поменять?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko В другом тоже не работает

Comment: у вас где-то проблема и к сожалению я думаю что здесь вам ничем не помогут, так как ваш код полностью рабочий :(

Comment: я попробовал у себя в проекте и все нормально показывает

Comment: попробуйте все удалить что связано с кнопкой и сделать с 0

Comment: Какая у вас минимальная версия? И на какой вы тестируете? Возможно у вас есть другие стили которые перекрывают на данной версии например: values-v21, тогда строку: <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/button_style</item> туда тоже нужно добавить.